# Phoenix - JDBCTemplate update

Tags: hbase, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, apache-phoenix

I have problem with upserting values in apache phoenix via Spring JdbcTemplate.
Query works fine, so i connect correctly with Phoenix. 
Also when i make update via straight JDBC it works.

Only when i use update method it does not produce any effect in database. 
There is no errors or warns. My code:

```
String sql = "upsert into fanpages(ID,NAME,CATEGORY) VALUES (7, 'new', 'new')";
jdbcTemplateObject.update(sql);
```

Console:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing SQL update [upsert into fanpages(ID,NAME,CATEGORY) VALUES (7, 'new', 'new')]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQL update affected 1 rows
```

Did i miss something? Why it does not work?

Comment: How did you tried to check the effect in the database?

Comment: I used SQuirreL SQL client.

Comment: make sure there is primary key in your query. Is ID your primary key?

Comment: Yes. Id is primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried invoking `commit`? I used `jaydebeapi`, which is a python module, to upsert into a phoenix table. Only when I called `commit` can the value be truly be upserted into the table.